# xbee and interoperability

Tags: arduino, rf, xbee, zigbee

i'm studying interoperability in the telecommunication field and i want to know we must do what to have an xbee module interoperable with other zigbee devices of other manufacturers (not Digi). I didn't understand what is the meaning of "zigbee feature set" and i am wondering if me as a user i have to pay zigbee alliance's loyalties in order to communicate with other devices

i am waiting for your responses 
thank you !!

Answer (score 1):

Only the XBee [products with "ZB" in the name](http://www.digi.com/xbee/) provide *"Interoperability with ZigBee devices from other vendors"*

As I understand it:

1. the products with "ZB" in the name have the "Zigbee Feature Set" included in the device firmware. The code enables the device to use the Zigbee protocols needed to interoperate with Zigbee devices from other manufacturers.
2. People purchasing XBee "ZB" products from Digi do not have to pay a separate royalty payment to the Zigbee Alliance if the products are for their own use.
3. If you plan on incorporating Zigbee capable components into a product or service that you will be selling to other people, you need to read the legalese and that probably means
   paying annual membership fees to the Zigbee Alliance

Caveat: I'm just some random person on the Internet, it usually isn't prudent to make legal or financial business decisions without paying a competent professional for advice.